# use database to keep track log in attempt

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I know this question might be duplicate of other similar questions but I couldn't find a proper answer, sorry if I didn't show you the code becuase I am not sure how to do it.

I try to create a login page in PHP, but I want to keep track of the users log in attempt if they didn't sucessfully log in. I assume using database but don't know how exactly to do it.

what I want is that when people failed after three attempt it should generate an alert dialogue (modal window will be even better) and when user click OK in the alert the log in window should be closed as well.

After that if the user go to the login page again, the login form should not be shown to the user again within an hour, I assume to use ip or session to block it. But since the user not logged in, I don't know if I can store the ip in the database. s

Can anyone help me with that? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

just simply include an insert statement on the part of your code that is doing the login process then everytime the user fails to login that will trigger the query but still checks the database if he is able to do the attempt 3 times you could also do it with ajax if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a PHP/JavaScript implementation of exactly what you are trying to do. It keeps track of the user's attempts with PHP sessions, and if the user attempts more than a certain number of times, it prevents additional login attempts for a certain number of seconds. Every time the user fails after that, it increases the number of seconds he has to wait to login again. All the parameters can be customized too.

Here is the project page and download: http://www.danedesigns.com/powerauth.php